# c# - How to open a local html file in a web browser that is not the default one?

Tags: c#, html, browser

I am trying to open a local html file in a web browser that is not the default one. Up to now, I can open an html file in the default web browser with :

`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("  File location  ");`

But is there a way to open this file in a web browser that is not the default?

It would be great if I can obtain a webBrowser object by the process. I already find how to determine if the desired web browser is opened with:

`var runningProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome"); if (runningProcess.Length != 0) { }`

Also I can't change the default web browser.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to open a website in chrome from c#, try:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("chrome", "www.google.com");
```

Using your code, I think you're trying to get any open browser first?

```
var runningProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
if (runningProcess.Length != 0)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("chrome", filename);
}
runningProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("firefox");
if (runningProcess.Length != 0)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("firefox", filename);
}
runningProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("iexplore");
if (runningProcess.Length != 0)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("iexplore", filename);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use below code:

Online page :

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe", "http://wwww.testdomain.com/mypage.html");
```

Offline Page:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe", "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\mypage.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ProcessStartInfo sInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("http://url.com/");  
Process.Start(sInfo);
```

[See the microsoft article about this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320478)

Comment: MS Link is broken